# Is driver certificate on Windows 10 always require?

Tags: windows, windows-10, certificate, kernel, driver

Can someone please help me to understand several question that arise in me head.

1. Is driver signing required if you load driver dynamically via win32 service API. I don't find any information that say at least something about this situation, some mention been [here](https://www.osr.com/blog/2015/07/24/questions-answers-windows-10-driver-signing/), but there is too little information to help me.
2. If it need, is it must be EV cert., or it only need for driver that loading during OS sturt up. Everywhere I looked it was said that after one of updatae EV cert. don't need only if Secure Boot is disabled, otherwise the installation via the .inf file will not happen ([example](https://www.osr.com/nt-insider/2016-issue1/today-in-driver-signing/)), but again nothing about the case in the first question.

For me it seems that i can't make and distribute program that use some kernel functionality as solo developer and learning kernel programing, at least on windows, it's just not relevant, exept if you just want write some utility for you machine for fun, or i wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, except if you selected `Disable driver signature enforcement` at Windows startup.
2. The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/get-a-code-signing-certificate) says that an EV certificate is required, but I'm not sure if it's a mandatory requirement.
3. Yes. AFAIK, a **LEGAL** signature must be purchased in the name of a company.
   Of course, you can `Disable driver signature enforcement` to learn kernel driver programing, and you can also ask your users to do so when you distribute your programs.

Comment: thanks, about 3rd question, is this way to disable checking for specific driver, so that user can stay safe and use my program if his trust me?

Comment: @Akros AFAIK, there is no **LEGITIMATE** way to do this. Sorry I can't say more. :)